# Magento2- getLastRealOrderId() returns null

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I am creating a payment gateway. When ever the last order has the state/status as `complete`, `getLastRealOrderId()` returns `null`. Is there any work around or a way to solve it ? I am new to magento

Comment: Hi, have You solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in block or in your helper class.

```
protected $_checkoutSession;
    protected $_orderFactory;
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
    }


    // Use this method to get ID    
    public function getRealOrderId()
    {
        $lastorderId = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastOrderId();
        return $lastorderId;
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        if ($this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId()) {
             $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId());
        return $order;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getShippingInfo()
    {
        $order = $this->getOrder();
        if($order) {
            $address = $order->getShippingAddress();    

            return $address;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Using this function, you can get the latest order Id. Hope this will help you too.

Comment: The problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

I think your question lacks a bit more context but I can talk about the default Magento checkout process.

If you check the code in Magento, you'll notice this information is set on Checkout Session by [this method](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php#L747).

That said, something on your checkout process is probably clearing the checkout session information before the process reaches the success page.

A simple and easier workaround for this is making your payment method set a different value on the Magento session and then grabbing it rather than the default checkout one (`getLastRealOrderId`). Or you can debug your process with Xdebug by watching the checkout session throughout the process to understand where it's being cleared or modified.

I'd put breakpoints throughout the code wherever there's a call to `setLastRealOrderId()` to see how it goes.